# How to access to first structure from second one - c

Tags: c

So here is code, that i can't understand. The thing i can't understand is how to access to structure "town" from structure counties. Also i don't know how to write in structure town and also how to access them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct town {
    char name[64];
    unsigned number;
};
struct country {
    char name[64];
    struct town capital;
    struct town *towns;
    unsigned number_of_towns;
};

int main() {
    struct country countries[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Name of country: ");
        scanf("%s", countries[i].name);
        scanf("%s", countries->towns->name); //this is what i try.
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pick one: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/7076153)

Comment: What is `struct grad`?  You don't have a definition for that.

Comment: I think you mean `struct town` instead of `struct grad`.

Comment: oh sorry.. i was translating this from Croatian to English so i forgot to translate that.

Comment: @MarkoSimic What exactly are you trying to achieve in this code currently?

Comment: `scanf("%s", countries->towns[i]->name);` Maybe, It's what you need. `towns` is an array in `contry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to get a variable of type `struct town` ?

```
struct town v ;
```

### How to access it?

```
v.name[i] --> ith charcter of `name`
v.number
```

### How to read them?

```
scanf("%s",v.name);
scanf("%u",&v.number);
```

### Now how to access them from other struct?

In case you use pointer `struct  town *` you need something so that you can point to it. You need to gather some more variable which you can use to store your information.

`struct town capital;// it doesn't need to point to anyone.`

`struct town* towns; // I need variable(s) of type struct town so that I can point to it.`

`towns= malloc(sizeof (struct town)* AS_MANY_AS_YOU_NEED);`//suppose you allocate for 4

you need to access them.

so what you do?

You can access each of these struct town type variable like this

`town[i]` and then you can access them as I have shown before.

### Do I need to allocate always more than 1 element?

Ofcourse not. You can have soething like

`towns = malloc(sizeof (struct town));`

access it like this `towns[0]` or simply `*(towns+0)` or `*towns`

### What is allocating ?

Allocating memory to store something from free store of memory.

### Help me more!!

Okay so you allocated some more variables in `towns` i-th of which can be accessed like `towns[i]` and

it's

- name can be accessed like `towns[i].name` .
- number can be in `towns[i].number`
- character of `name` for a particular town `towns[i].name[i]`

### How to access them from countries?

```
  struct country {
        char name[64];        //countries[i].name
        struct town capital;  //countries[i].capital.name or countries[i].capital.number
        struct town *towns;   // (countries[i]->towns[i]).name or ...
        unsigned number_of_towns;
    } countries[5];
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. This is what i need :))

Answer (score 0):

Please try if this code can help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct town {
    char name[64];
    unsigned number;
};
struct country {
    char name[64];
    struct town capital;
    struct town *towns;
    unsigned number_of_towns;
};

int main() {
    struct country countries[5];
    struct town *twn;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Name of country: ");
        scanf("%s", countries[i].name);
        twn = malloc(sizeof(struct town));
        printf("Name of town 0: ");
        scanf("%s", twn->name);
        countries[i].towns = twn;
    }
    printf("*** Print Countries ***\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Name of country: %s\n", countries[i].name);
        printf("Name of town 0: %s\n", countries[i].towns->name);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        free(countries[i].towns);
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
Name of country: one
Name of town 0: onetown
Name of country: two
Name of town 0: twotown
Name of country: three
Name of town 0: threetown
Name of country: four
Name of town 0: fourtown
Name of country: five
Name of town 0: fivetown
*** Print Countries ***
Name of country: one
Name of town 0: onetown
Name of country: two
Name of town 0: twotown
Name of country: three
Name of town 0: threetown
Name of country: four
Name of town 0: fourtown
Name of country: five
Name of town 0: fivetown
```

Comment: Thank you.. I will try this code. But post above explained exactly what i had problems with.

Comment: @MarkoSimic Yes, it seems you must use `malloc`. It is good to know how to use `malloc`. Your program can be written in many ways, I suppose. Good luck!